# Data not showing in primary mdf file only in the mdf file in the bin/debug folder

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a project which I can save data about a student in a databse using visual studeio and c#. Whenever I save the data it will only save to the mdf file in the debug folder not update back to the primary mdf file, why could this be?

Comment: Nice. Some more details would be helpfull.

Comment: Whenever I create a new record I can see that the new record is updated to the mdf in the debug folder but, whenever I check the mdf in the Project folder there are no records.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you start running your project or build, It will be compiled and will run into the **Debug** or **Release** folder, so thus it will also get a copy of your **mdf** file from project folder and paste into the **Debug** folder. So you will be having all latest data performed during that run into the Debug or **Release** folder. Once you re run the project it will vanish all last changes and will give you fresh copy of the **mdf** file.

Comment: Whenever i create new record where does it save too the Debug or the project?

Comment: It will save to Debug only.

Comment: How do I get it to update the mdf in the project folder because at the minute it only saves to the Debug

Comment: try to set mdf files property copy to output to never in your solution exploper.

Comment: I tried that but, on the form load the table adapter fill line produced an error,                                                                                                           An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file F:\MSOMDatabase\MSOMDatabase\bin\Debug\MSOMDatabase1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.